# Output levels of FM broadcast signals

Tags: frequency-modulation

I wrote an FM mono transmitter with HackRF, and now I'm trying to add stereo and RDS. I'm confused about the levels of the final mono + stereo + RDS mix (after preemphasis, and before the FM modulator).

There are some images around the Internet, like this one from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting#/media/File:RDS_vs_DirectBand_FM-spectrum2.svg but there is no label on the Y scale, so I can't understand how the
amplitude levels are related at the transmitter.

I also found this: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/73.322 but I can't understand how to translate the description there to amplitude levels.

I decided to capture some signals around me with an rtlsdr and some of them look very different from others (and from the wikipedia image), for example:
[image: 88.0 MHz]
[image: 91.0 MHz]
[image: 106.9 MHz]

Comment: Have you browsed through ITU recommendations to broadcast standards?

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.412-9-199812-I!!PDF-E.pdf